# Select max of colA in each colB using group by in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in sqlite. I am trying to get the max of ColA of each ColB.

My table looks like this:

```
select * from table1

ColA           |          ColB
63.9                       1234            
9.09                       1234             
52                         1678              
8.65                       1678              
7.07                       0987              
54                         0987              
23                         9876
```

I would like to query the max of ColA from each ColB. 
And the output expected is :

```
MaxofColA            |          ColB
63.9                            1234              
52                              1678              
54                              0987              
23                              9876
```

I need the sqlite query for this? When I try the below query I get max of ColA for some groups of ColB but not for the rest.
My result is:

```
MaxOfColA          |       ColB
9.09                       1234 ---- incorrect
8.65                       1678 ---- incorrect
54                         0987 ---- correct
23                         9876 ---- correct
```

Comment: You kinda answered yourself. Select max of colA grouping by ColB. Just write it in SQL

Comment: I have written the query select Max(ColA) AS MaxOfColA, ColB
from table1 group by table1.ColB;   But it seems not to work in sqlite. How can I handle it in sqlite?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Add your try and it's output to the question

Comment: Which SQLite version are you using?

Comment: SQLite version is 3.9.2

Comment: The query should work. Try `select cola from t where colb = 1234' order by cola` to see how SQLite orders the values.

Comment: This has probably to do with SQLite's loose typing. You cannot really declare a column as a precise numeric type with decimals. (It only knows text or approximate types, such as real, and even these are merely seen as suggestions as to what to store in the column). SQLite may go as far as store different types in one column, e.g. REAL 63.90000000000001 and TEXT '9.09  '.

Comment: When I try the query suggested by Thorsten Kettner, I find that SQLite orders the output as 63.9 and the 9.09 showing that 9.09 to be the max. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Looks like alphabetical order. `select cola, typeof(cola) from t` to check this. I don't know SQLite well enough to give a solution. Column type should probably be text with affinity numeric, and inserts should insert 9.09 and not '9.09'. Maybe one can somehow even force a field's type - I don't know.

Comment: Yes, it seems to store the values in text and when I changed the column type. It seems to work.